# Как заархивировать директорию Compress::Zlib в Perl

Tags: perl, zlib

В дирректорию /home/logs/app/ пишутся csv файлы. Нужно директорию app упаковать и получить архив в /home/logs/.
Сейчас делаю системным вызовом "system ('zip -jr '/home/logs/app/logs.zip '/home/logs/app/log/');"
Хочу избавиться от системного вызова и использовать Compress::Zlib.

Пытался запускать так

```
my @files = ('log_01','log_02','log_03');
my $dirname = 'app';
my $path = '/home/logs/';

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open(FILE,$path.$dirname.'/'.$file) or die "$!";
    my $gz = gzopen($gzfile, 'ab');
    while(<FILE>){
        my $byteswritten = $ gz-> gzwrite ($_);
    }
    $gz->gzclose();
    close(FILE);
}
```

Однако на выходе получаю архив с файлом log, без расширения. Если его открыть, то в нем простыня информации из файлов.

Как мне получить архив в котором будет директория log, а уже в ней все файлы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, эта библиотека преназначена в основном для сжатия данных в памяти и не рассчитана на многофайловые архивы. Попробуйте взять Archive::Zip. В нем можно не особо заморачиваясь упаковать или директорию:

```
my $dir_member = $zip->addDirectory( 'dirname/' );
```

или отдельно файлы, с возможностью переименования и назначения виртуального пути:

```
my $file_member = $zip->addFile( 'xyz.pl', 'fakedir/AnotherName.pl' );
```

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, что это мне может помочь)